# How to set individual indices in Numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to use arrays to set values in other arrays. Unfortunately instead of setting a value it is somehow overwriting a bunch of values. What is going on, and how can I achieve what I want?

```
>>> target = np.array( [ [0,1],[1,2],[2,3] ])
>>> target
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 3]])
>>> actions = np.array([0,0,0])
>>> target[actions] #The first row, 3 times
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1]])
>>> target[:,actions] #The first column, 3 times
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2]])
>>> values = np.array([7,8,9])
>>> target[:,actions] = values #why isnt this working?
>>> target
array([[9, 1],
       [9, 2],
       [9, 3]])
#Actually want
#array([[7, 1],
#       [8, 2],
#       [9, 3]])

>>> target = np.array( [ [0,1],[1,2],[2,3] ]) #reset to original value
>>> actions = np.array([0,1,0])
>>> target[:,actions] = values.reshape(3, 1)
array([[7, 7],
       [8, 8],
       [9, 9]])
#Actually want
#array([[7, 1],
#       [1, 8],
#       [9, 3]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`target[:,actions]` selects the same column of `target` thrice.

When you say `target[:,actions] = values`, what you are doing is:

1. Assign 7 to all the values in the column, three times.
2. Assign 8 to all the values in the column, three times.
3. Assign 9 to all the values in the column, three times.

So you end up with 9 in all the values in the column.

If you insist on this awkward triple-writing of data, you can fix it by transposing the write:

```
target[:,actions] = values.reshape(3, 1)
```

This will write `[7,8,9]` to the column, three times.  Obviously that's wasteful, and you could do this instead:

```
target[:,actions[-1]] = values
```

The effect should be the same, and it saves computation.

Comment: Yay it works! I guess the main issue is that values is a "row" when we really need a "column". That's crazy that is sets it 3 times though! Makes sense I suppose. The `[-1]` is a complete mystery to me, what's happening there? How does it change each "iteration"? This is all I could find on negative indices: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html. Thank you so much!

Comment: The `[-1]` means "take the last index."  Since the first two writes are useless, this skips them.

Comment: Ah ok. So this wouldn't work if actions wasn't all the same value right? You'd have to use the reshape method. I just tried it with `actions=[0,1,0]`, the negative method gave me the same array as [0,0,0], and the reshape method gave me 2 columns of [7,8,9]. In this case I'd actually want [ [7,1], [1,8], [9,3] ]

Comment: @JamesL.: Oh I see, that's different to what your original question asked.  Well, as you've already posted in your own answer, you need `target[np.arange(3),actions] = np.array([7, 8, 9])` in this case (and you can use this solution in the `[0,0,0]` case as well).  You do not want `:` for this--you can plainly see what you're selecting, and it's correct using `arange()` instead.

Comment: Ok my mistake! I really appreciate your writeup though. I thought `:` was correct for something like this and that `arange` would be less efficient, but I guess it's actually the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

2 ways to write [7,8,9] to the first column:

basic indexing (with slice):

```
In [396]: target[:,0] = [7,8,9]           # all rows, 1st column
In [397]: target
Out[397]: 
array([[7, 1],
       [8, 2],
       [9, 3]])
```

Advanced indexing (with 2 lists)

```
In [398]: target[[0,1,2],[0,0,0]] = [7,8,9]   # pair [0,0],[1,0],[2,0]
In [399]: target
Out[399]: 
array([[7, 1],
       [8, 2],
       [9, 3]])
```

The 2nd method also works for a mix of columns:

```
In [400]: target = np.array( [ [0,1],[1,2],[2,3] ])
In [401]: target[[0,1,2],[0,1,0]] = [7,8,9]
In [402]: target
Out[402]: 
array([[7, 1],
       [1, 8],
       [9, 3]])
```

Broadcasting comes into play.  In a case like this the are 3 potential arrays to broadcast - the 2 dimensions and the source array.

Advanced indexing like this produces a 1d array.  So the source array has to match:

```
In [403]: target[[0,1,2],[0,1,0]]
Out[403]: array([7, 8, 9])
```

A (1,3) can broadcast to (3,), but a (3,1) can't:

```
In [404]: target[[0,1,2],[0,1,0]] = np.array([[7,8,9]])
In [405]: target[[0,1,2],[0,1,0]] = np.array([[7,8,9]]).T
...
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (3,1) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (3,)
```

This sort of indexing is unusual.  Note that the result is (3,3).

```
In [412]: target[:,[0,0,0]]
Out[412]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2]])
```

A (3,1) source:

```
In [413]: np.array([[7,8,9]]).T
Out[413]: 
array([[7],
       [8],
       [9]])
In [414]: target[:,[0,0,0]] = _
In [415]: target
Out[415]: 
array([[7, 1],
       [8, 2],
       [9, 3]])
```

The (3,1) can broadcast to (3,3).  It works, but ends up assigning [7,8,9] 3 times, all to the same 0 column.

---

Another way of assigning the 1st column:

```
In [423]: target[np.ix_([0,1,2],[0,0,0])]
Out[423]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2]])
```

Again a (3,3), with accepts a (3,1):

```
In [424]: target[np.ix_([0,1,2],[0,0,0])] = np.array([[7,8,9]]).T
In [425]: target
Out[425]: 
array([[7, 1],
       [8, 2],
       [9, 3]])
```

`ix_` makes 2 arrays that can broadcast against each other, in this case a column vector and a row one:

```
In [426]: np.ix_([0,1,2],[0,0,0])
Out[426]: 
(array([[0],
        [1],
        [2]]), array([[0, 0, 0]]))
```

I can select all elements of `target` with:

```
In [430]: target[np.ix_([0,1,2],[0,1])]
Out[430]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 3]])
```

and in a jumbled order:

```
In [431]: target[np.ix_([2,0,1],[1,0])]
Out[431]: 
array([[3, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [2, 1]])
```

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't get it to work using `:` indexing, however the following is functional by using an array of indices. Not sure why the `:` method is not working, if someone can come up with a way to fix that I will accept it instead.

```
>>> target = np.array( [ [0,1],[1,2],[2,3] ])
>>> rows = np.arange(target.shape[0])
>>> actions = np.array([0,1,0])
>>> values = np.array([7,8,9])
>>> target[rows,actions] = values
>>> target
array([[7, 1],
       [1, 8],
       [9, 3]])
```